# python error in main method defenetion

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

this my first python code , i am trying to connect to data base , i think the connection part was processed successfully

```
import MySQLdb

class Database:
        host = "localhost"
        user = "root"
        passwd = "root"
        db = "pitest"

        def __init__(self):
                self.connection = MySQLdb.connect( host = self.host,
                                                   user = self.user,
                                                   passwd = self.passwd,
                                                   db = self.db)
        def query(self, q):
                cursor = self.connection.cursor( MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor )
                cursor.execute(q)

                return cursor.fetchall()

        def __del__(self):
                self.connection.close()




         if __name__ == "__main__":
                db = Database()

                q = "DELETE FROM users"
                db.query(q)

                q = """
                INSERT INTO users (title, fname, sname, age, email)
                VALUES ('A', 'Z', 'BIG Z', '20', 'raspberrypi@example.com'),
               ('B', 'X', 'BIG X', '30', 'raspberrypi@example.com'),
               ('C', 'Y', 'BIG Y', '24', 'raspberrypi@example.com'),
               ('A', 'W', 'BIG W', '29', 'raspberrypi@example.com')
                """
```

Every time i try to run this code i get this error:

```
  File "mysqlConnection.py", line 26
    if __name__ == "__main__":
                             ^
```

can any one help me please

Comment: Indentation error, the `if __name__ == "__main__":` should be at the start of line, also colon(:) is needed at the end of the line.

Comment: @knight9631  i did that but it did not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an indentation error. Your

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

is not in the same indentation level as

```
def __del__(self):
```

Please fix it. I think hitting backspace once before your if block will do.